# Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to Sort `Users` Using lambda Expression. My Users class

```
public class Users
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

And My Sorting method

```
public List<Users> SortUsers(string sSortBy)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users), "Users");
    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(arg, sSortBy), typeof(object));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Users, object>>(body, arg);

    List<Users> UserList;
    UserList = UOWUser.UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(lambda).ToList(); // Error here
    return UserList;
}
```

I am Accessing the method by

```
List<Users> UserList;
UserList = objUsers.SortUsers("FirstName");
```

I am passing `sSortBy` as `string` (here "FirstName")

> Error :Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'.

Comes in line `UserList = UOWUser.UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(lambda).ToList();`

**EDIT**

```
public List<Users> SortUsers(string sSortBy)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users), "Users");
    var TType = Expression.Property(arg, sSortBy).Type;
    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(arg, sSortBy), TType);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Users, object>>(body, arg);// Error here  :: Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'   
    List<Users> UserList;
    UserList = UOWUser.UsersRepository.Entities.OrderBy(lambda).ToList(); 
    return UserList;
}
```

Works fine with  `UserList = objUsers.SortUsers("FirstName");` But Gives Error When  `UserList = objUsers.SortUsers("DateCreated");`

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Object'

any help would be appreciated Thank you

Comment: I think you need to pass  `typeof(string)` instead of  `typeof(object)` in the Convert method

Comment: @Selman22 Thanks for your feedback , but typeof(string) can be used only for string properties, if i have to sort by Id then it should be typeof(int), So i can't and need a general method ,should work for string ,int , datetime etc, so i used typeof(object)

Comment: hmm, then get your property type with reflection and then pass it? like: `typeof(Users).GetProperty(sSortBy).PropertyType`

Comment: @Selman22 Tried your suggestion , But failed ,Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
public static List<Users> SortUsers(string sSortBy)
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users), "Users");
    var sortProperty = Expression.Property(arg, sSortBy);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(sortProperty, arg);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<Users>));
    var orderByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { typeof(Users), sortProperty.Type }, new Expression[] { param, lambda });
    var orderLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<Users>, IQueryable<Users>>>(orderByCall, param).Compile();

    List<Users> UserList;
    UserList = orderLambda(UOWUser.UsersRepository.Entities).ToList(); // Error here
    return UserList;
}
```

It makes the entire `source.OrderBy(x => x.PropName)` through `Expression`, so you don't have to actually specify `x.PropName` type.